# Flex, Change the title of a view based on previous view's data

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm staring at the following code

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title='{this.data.name}'
    xmlns:model="model.*"
```

I was hoping to change the views title depending upon the data is gets from the previous view. At the moment its simply blank.

when title is:

```
title='{this.data}'
```

I get...

> [object Object]

Anyone have some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What's not working with `{this.data.name}`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the object in the debugger. Maybe instead of 'name' it has a property like 'txt' or 'title'.